# Cloud computing for ICCF?

Tags: stockfish

I’ve been looking for a cloud computing service that can run the latest stockfish dev build. Chessify only goes to stockfish 16 and I can’t for the life of me figure out chessbase. If the answer is a generic cloud service, like google or amazon, can you provide a link to instructions on how to set up stockfish dev build? And if stockfish dev build is on chessbase, how do I use it? I am aware of next chess move but I want to calculate for longer than 30 seconds.

Comment: Have you tried running them on your own PC? Do you have any experience running cloud services?

Comment: I’ve run devbuild on my own hardware before. I have never used a cloud service, but I was interested because people have been saying that they were able to make calculations that would take several weeks on standard hardware.

Comment: You can find tutorials for setting up a standard Ubuntu AWS VM with many cores and lots of RAM. It will cost you, though.

Comment: Thanks qwr, you’ve pointed me in the right direction

Comment: Since you found it helpful, I fleshed out my comments as an answer.

Comment: I am using VM on azure for iccf play - if you don't leave it running overnight its not overly expensive if you deallocate machine after usage (you are only billed for cpu when machine is allocated). Simplest installation is to just use linux vm, rdp to it and then follow instructions for local installation of stockfish. Probably you will also want a gui - I think scid is the best free one.

Answer (score 1):

[Stockfish dev releases](https://github.com/official-stockfish/Stockfish/releases) are packaged as standard Ubuntu and Windows binaries that should run out-of-the-box. There are many tutorials out there on setting up an AWS EC2 (or another cloud provider) Ubuntu instance with lots of cores and RAM.

It'll cost you though. For example, chess.com CCC uses 2x AMD EPYC 7H12 with 256 cores and 512 GB RAM. Looking at https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ for 128 vCPUs, depending on your region it'll cost several dollars per hour. Which AWS instance to use would be an interesting follow-up question.

Comment: I’m wondering how much time is a factor in these things. For example, google has a 416 vcore with 12 TB of ram for 80 an hour. Would one minute, about a dollar and forty cents, be enough to reach nutball depths and be better than say running a 64 core thread ripper for several hours? I will find out soon enough.

Comment: I'd be interested if you wrote up your benchmarks. I don't have much experience with this kinda thing except for a brief foray into eth mining.